# Jetpack Compose Using Same State Value For All Screens

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to show circularProgressIndicator while an operation is working such as network call. I want to be able to change the indicator visibility state in all viewmodels and observe that value in NavHost because I want to show a transparant layout which has a circular indicator and prevent user from clicking another fields while network call is still going.

I tried to use baseviewmodel class and mutableStateOf(Boolean) in it but whenever I tried to  access viewmodel from navhost it's instance is different than other.

Question is basically how can i create a single global mutableStateOf() object and change it's value from all inside of my viewmodels and observe it as a state inside of NavHost composable to change visibility of circularProgressIndicator?

Note: I am using hilt to get instance of viewmodel -> viewModel: MyViewModel = hiltViewModel()

```
@Composable
fun NavHost(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {

val navController = rememberAnimatedNavController()

Box {

    AnimatedNavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = Screen.EmailAndPassword.route,
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {

        composable(Screen.EmailAndPassword.route) {
            EmailAndPasswordScreen {
                navController.navigate(Screen.UserInformation.route) {
                    /*TODO*/
                }
            }
        }
        composable(Screen.UserInformation.route) { UserInformationScreen() }
    }
    
    LoadingScreen(isVisible = /* IndicatorState */)
}}

@Composable
fun LoadingScreen(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, isVisible: Boolean) {
if (isVisible){
   Box(modifier = modifier.background(Color.Transparent).fillMaxSize(), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
       CircularProgressIndicator()
   }
 }}
```

Comment: Do it on your main class where you used scaffold. Because compose working on single activity design pattern

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to use baseviewmodel class and mutableStateOf(Boolean) in it but whenever I tried to access viewmodel from navhost it's instance is different than other.

I use [`Compose-Destinations`](https://github.com/raamcosta/compose-destinations) library and for sharing a ViewModel throughout the Activity, I do it like this (This is a sample from documentation):

```
@Composable
fun AppNavigation(
    activity: Activity
) {
    DestinationsNavHost(
        //...
        dependenciesContainerBuilder = { //this: DependenciesContainerBuilder<*>

            //  To tie SettingsViewModel to "settings" nested navigation graph, 
            // making it available to all screens that belong to it
            dependency(NavGraphs.settings) {
                val parentEntry = remember(navBackStackEntry) {
                    navController.getBackStackEntry(NavGraphs.settings.route)
                }
                hiltViewModel<SettingsViewModel>(parentEntry)
            }

            //  To tie ActivityViewModel to the activity, making it available to all destinations
            dependency(hiltViewModel<ActivityViewModel>(activity))
        }
    )
}
```