# Share viewmodel from activity to compose function using hilt

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel, dagger-hilt, jetpack-compose-navigation

My app uses hilt and I have some work with `LoadManager` inside my activity that read contacts using `ContentResolver` and when I finish work I get the cursor that I send to my viewModel in order to process the data and do some business logic which for that I declared the following on top of my activity :

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity(), LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
    private val contactsViewModel: ContactsViewModel by viewModels()
 ...
```

such that I use it inside `onLoadFinished`  :

```
    override fun onLoadFinished(loader: Loader<Cursor>, cursor: Cursor?) {
  
                contactsViewModel.updateContactsListFromCursor(cursor, loader.id)
     }
```

Inside my viewModel I have the following code which updates the ui state of the list with the contacts to be displayed:

```
data class ContactsListUiState(
    val contacts: MutableList<Contact>,
    val searchFilter: String)

@HiltViewModel
class ContactsViewModel @Inject constructor() : ViewModel() {
    private val _contactsListUiState =
        MutableStateFlow(ContactsListUiState(mutableStateListOf(), ""))
    val contactsListUiState: StateFlow<ContactsListUiState> = _contactsListUiState.asStateFlow()

    private fun updateContactsList(filter: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            ...

            _contactsListUiState.update { currentState ->
                currentState.copy(contacts = list, searchFilter = filter)
            }
        }
```

Finally, I am supposed to display the contacts that a `LazyColumn` and I pass the viewModel to my composable function using hilt following the official documentation :

```
@Composable
fun ContactsListScreen(
       navController: NavController,
       modifier: Modifier = Modifier, viewModel: ContactsViewModel = hiltViewModel()
   ) {
       val uiState by viewModel.contactsListUiState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
       ...
```

But when i access `uiState.contacts` it is empty and my lists does not show anything and I also noticed that the `contactsViewModel` which I used in the activity is not the same viewModel instance that I got from `hiltViewModel()` inside the composable function which probably causes this problem..

Any suggestions how to share the sameViewModel between the activity and the composable functions assuming that I have to call the viewModel from the onLoadFinished function(which is not composable) where I get the cursor therefore I must have a viewModel reference inside the activity itself

Comment: Check if this answer helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74269746/jetpack-compose-using-same-state-value-for-all-screens/74277703#74277703

Comment: It is not really what I am looking for, in my case the viewModel inside the activity is not the same instance inside the composable functions

Comment: Have you tried doing some Log printing inside the `ViewModel's` `init{…}`  block and verifying its not being called more than once?

Comment: It is for sure being called more than once, I logged both hashCodes of the viewModel inside the activity and the viewModel inside the composable functions and I saw that they are different.. So for sure the initialization of the viewModel with `by viewModels()` inside the activity provides a different instance than the `hiltViewModel()` inside the composable functions

Comment: Interesting.. I'm actually trying to re-produce your posted code, but its weird I'm having the same instance of the ViewModel, I'm trying to make a different instance of the ViewModel but I keep getting the same one.. Ill try to get back to this when I'm able to re-produce it..

Comment: thats wierd.. isnt the `hiltViewModel()` supposed to be scoped to the "closest" `LifeCycleOwner` ? in this is is my activity

Comment: I am trying to think of a work around for calling the viewModel somehow inside the activity, as for now I am calling it from the `onLoadFinished` callback which is not composable so I cannot use `hiltViewModel()` there..

Comment: just want to ask if you can try, would you mind using the composable `viewModel()` factory instead of `hiltViewModel()`? just to check if it would make any difference, -`androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.viewModel`

Comment: Ok I found something, both `viewModel()` and `hiltViewModel()` seems to work only when I pass in the activity as the `ViewModelStoreOwner` like `hiltViewModel(this)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249943/discussion-between-yarin-shitrit-and-z-y).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the [docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/hilt).

> The function hiltViewModel() returns an existing ViewModel or **creates
> a new one scoped to the current navigation graph present on the
> NavController back stack**. The function can optionally take a
> NavBackStackEntry to scope the ViewModel to a parent back stack entry.

It turns out the factories create a new instance of the ViewModel when they are part of a Navigation Graph. But since you already found out that to make it work you have to specify the `ViewModelStoreOwner`, so I took an approach based my recent answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74424253/super-onbackpressed-in-jetpack-compose/74427398#74427398), and created a CompositionLocal of the current activity since its extending `ComponentActivity` being it as a `ViewModelStoreOwner` itself.

Here's my short attempt that reproduces your issue with the possible fix.

Activity

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class HiltActivityViewModelActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    private val myViewModel: ActivityScopedViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
                CompositionLocalProvider(LocalActivity provides this@HiltActivityViewModelActivity) {
                    Log.e("ActivityScopedViewModel", "Hashcode: ${myViewModel.hashCode()} : Activity Scope")
                    HiltActivitySampleNavHost()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
@HiltViewModel
class ActivityScopedViewModel @Inject constructor(): ViewModel() {}
```

Local Activity Composition

```
val LocalActivity = staticCompositionLocalOf<ComponentActivity> {
    error("LocalActivity is not present")
}
```

Simple Navigation Graph

```
enum class HiltSampleNavHostRoute {
    DES_A, DES_B
}

@Composable
fun HiltActivitySampleNavHost(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    navController: NavHostController = rememberNavController(),
    startDestination: String = HiltSampleNavHostRoute.DES_A.name
) {
    NavHost(
        modifier = modifier,
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = startDestination
    ) {

        composable(HiltSampleNavHostRoute.DES_A.name) {
            DestinationScreenA()
        }

        composable(HiltSampleNavHostRoute.DES_B.name) {
            DestinationScreenB()
        }
    }
}
```

Screens

```
// here you can use the Local Activity as the ViewModelStoreOwner
@Composable
fun DestinationScreenA(
    myViewModelParam: ActivityScopedViewModel = hiltViewModel(LocalActivity.current)
    // myViewModelParam: ActivityScopedViewModel = viewModel(LocalActivity.current)
) {
    Log.e("ActivityScopedViewModel", "Hashcode: ${myViewModelParam.hashCode()} : Composable Scope")
}

@Composable
fun DestinationScreenB(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {}
```

Or better yet, like from this answer by [Phil Dukhov](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69002018/why-a-new-viewmodel-is-created-in-each-compose-navigation-route), you can use `LocalViewModelStoreOwner` as the parameter when you invoke the builder.

Same NavHost

```
@Composable
fun HiltActivitySampleNavHost(
    ...
) {

    val viewModelStoreOwner = checkNotNull(LocalViewModelStoreOwner.current) {
        "No ViewModelStoreOwner was provided via LocalViewModelStoreOwner"
    }

    NavHost(
        modifier = modifier,
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = startDestination
    ) {

        composable(HiltSampleNavHostRoute.DES_A.name) {
            DestinationScreenA(
                myViewModelParam = viewModel(viewModelStoreOwner)
            )
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

Both logs from the activity and the composable in the nav graph shows the same hashcode

```
E/ActivityScopedViewModel: Hashcode: 267094635 : Activity Scope
E/ActivityScopedViewModel: Hashcode: 267094635 : Composable Scope
```

Also have a look at [Thracian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73844296/jetpack-compose-state-change-not-reflected-across-activities). It has a very detailed explanation about `ComponentActivity`, and based from it I think my first proposed solution would probably work in your case.